# В IDE Arduino для ESP32-cam не могу запустить OpenCV

Tags: opencv, arduino, ide

Все способы сопряжены с python, а мне нужно чтобы openCV без дополнительной отсылки компилировалась и загружалась только на коде в в IDE Arduino.

У меня есть код, но моих знаний в c++ не хватает чтобы добавить туда библиотеку OpenCV да еще и в IDE Arduino

```
#include <WebServer.h>
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <esp32cam.h>

 
const char* WIFI_SSID = "TP-Link_0441";
const char* WIFI_PASS = "15273031";
 
WebServer server(80);
 
 
static auto loRes = esp32cam::Resolution::find(320, 240);
static auto midRes = esp32cam::Resolution::find(350, 530);
static auto hiRes = esp32cam::Resolution::find(800, 600);
void serveJpg()
{
 auto frame = esp32cam::capture();
 if (frame == nullptr) {
 Serial.println("CAPTURE FAIL");
 server.send(503, "", "");
 return;
 }
 Serial.printf("CAPTURE OK %dx%d %db\n", frame->getWidth(), frame->getHeight(),
 static_cast<int>(frame->size()));
 
 server.setContentLength(frame->size());
 server.send(200, "image/jpeg");
 WiFiClient client = server.client();
 frame->writeTo(client);
}
 
void handleJpgLo()
{
 if (!esp32cam::Camera.changeResolution(loRes)) {
 Serial.println("SET-LO-RES FAIL");
 }
 serveJpg();
}
 
void handleJpgHi()
{
 if (!esp32cam::Camera.changeResolution(hiRes)) {
 Serial.println("SET-HI-RES FAIL");
 }
 serveJpg();
}
 
void handleJpgMid()
{
 if (!esp32cam::Camera.changeResolution(midRes)) {
 Serial.println("SET-MID-RES FAIL");
 }
 serveJpg();
}
 
 
void setup(){
 Serial.begin(115200);
 Serial.println();
 {
 using namespace esp32cam;
 Config cfg;
 cfg.setPins(pins::AiThinker);
 cfg.setResolution(hiRes);
 cfg.setBufferCount(2);
 cfg.setJpeg(80);
 
 bool ok = Camera.begin(cfg);
 Serial.println(ok ? "CAMERA OK" : "CAMERA FAIL");
 }
 WiFi.persistent(false);
 WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
 WiFi.begin(WIFI_SSID, WIFI_PASS);
 while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
 delay(500);
 }
 Serial.print("http://");
 Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
 Serial.println(" /cam-lo.jpg");
 Serial.println(" /cam-hi.jpg");
 Serial.println(" /cam-mid.jpg");
 
 server.on("/cam-lo.jpg", handleJpgLo);
 server.on("/cam-hi.jpg", handleJpgHi);
 server.on("/cam-mid.jpg", handleJpgMid);
 
 server.begin();
}
 
void loop()
{
 server.handleClient();
}

Если и добавляю вот так 
#include <WebServer.h>
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <esp32cam.h>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/objdetect/objdetect.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

const char* WIFI_SSID = "TP-Link_0441";
const char* WIFI_PASS = "15273031";

WebServer server(80);
CascadeClassifier face_cascade;

static auto loRes = esp32cam::Resolution::find(320, 240);
static auto midRes = esp32cam::Resolution::find(350, 530);
static auto hiRes = esp32cam::Resolution::find(800, 600);

void serveJpg()
{
    auto frame = esp32cam::capture();
    if (frame == nullptr) {
        Serial.println("CAPTURE FAIL");
        server.send(503, "", "");
        return;
    }
    Serial.printf("CAPTURE OK %dx%d %db\n", frame->getWidth(), frame->getHeight(), static_cast<int>(frame->size()));

    server.setContentLength(frame->size());
    server.send(200, "image/jpeg");
    WiFiClient client = server.client();
    frame->writeTo(client);
}

void handleJpgLo()
{
    if (!esp32cam::Camera.changeResolution(loRes)) {
        Serial.println("SET-LO-RES FAIL");
    }
    serveJpg();
}

void handleJpgHi()
{
    if (!esp32cam::Camera.changeResolution(hiRes)) {
        Serial.println("SET-HI-RES FAIL");
    }
    serveJpg();
}

void handleJpgMid()
{
    if (!esp32cam::Camera.changeResolution(midRes)) {
        Serial.println("SET-MID-RES FAIL");
    }
    serveJpg();
}

void setup(){
    Serial.begin(115200);
    Serial.println();
    {
        using namespace esp32cam;
        Config cfg;
        cfg.setPins(pins::AiThinker);
        cfg.setResolution(hiRes);
        cfg.setBufferCount(2);
        cfg.setJpeg(80);

        bool ok = Camera.begin(cfg);
        Serial.println(ok ? "CAMERA OK" : "CAMERA FAIL");
    }
    WiFi.persistent(false);
    WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
    WiFi.begin(WIFI_SSID, WIFI_PASS);
    while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
        delay(500);
    }
    Serial.print("http://");
    Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
    Serial.println(" /cam-lo.jpg");
    Serial.println(" /cam-hi.jpg");
    Serial.println(" /cam-mid.jpg");

    server.on("/cam-lo.jpg", handleJpgLo);
    server.on("/cam-hi.jpg", handleJpgHi);
    server.on("/cam-mid.jpg", handleJpgMid);

    server.begin();
}

void loop()
{
    server.handleClient();
}
```

то IDE выдает ошибку No such file or directory и ни include ни добавление нехватаемых файлов в соответствующую директорию не помогает,как быть не знаю